# Popup "What's SO for teams?" geometry should be more flexible in case of long translation

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, localization, stack-overflow-for-teams

Popup "What's SO for teams?" geometry should be more flexible in case of long translation. Currently on [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/):

> [image: Q&A for work]

The translation of sentence "Q&A for work" overlaps with an image of group of three.

Comment: Wasn't the Teams sidebar supposed to be disabled on the international sites for non-members of Teams?

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog by the looks of it the OP is a member of a Team?

Comment: @rene I'm the only member of my Team since yesterday announcement :)

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog teams sidebar available on ruSO even for non-logged-in users.

Answer (score 5):

We've removed this element from the left navigation as of earlier this week (Monday the 22nd of March) so this should no longer be an issue. Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: That's why I couldn't find it anymore.

Comment: Still is an issue on [rusSE](https://rus.stackexchange.com/), please look at [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387064/339911).