# Unable to translate "Looking for your Teams?"

Tags: bug, status-deferred, localization, transifex, stack-overflow-for-teams

On all SE sites with non-English user interface phrase "Looking for your Teams?" on the left part of the main page is not available to translation, e.g. [doesn't exist in traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Looking%20for%20your). For instance on [rusSE](https://rus.stackexchange.com/):

> [image: rus se]

Related sentence used in "i" popup [translated](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16208) long time ago, but translation seems unusable:

> [image: popup]

These items now appeared on SO family sites, e.g.: [Нет перевода для новой ссылки "Looking for your Teams?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12497/176217)